# Four bit calculator with overflow

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, calculator

I am trying to make a 4-bit calculator. 
The input is 2 numbers and a sign. The calculator is 4-bit,and if the number is bigger than 16, there might be overflow.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3jWj.jpg)

I have written the part with + and -, but i do not have an idea how to continue.

I will be very thankful if someone help me.

```
string[] asignb = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int a = int.Parse(asignb[0]);
string sign = asignb[1];
int b = int.Parse(asignb[2]);

if (a > 16) {
    a -= 16;
}

if (b > 16) {
    b -= 16;
}

if (sign == "+") {   
    int addition = 0;
    addition = a + b;

    if(addition > 16) {
        addition -= 16;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(addition);

} else if(sign == "-") {
    int subtraction = 0;
    subtraction = a - b;

    if (subtraction < 0) {
        subtraction += 16;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(subtraction);

}
```

Comment: Would be more appreciable. If you could upload what you've done so far

Comment: You can use modulo for positive integers. You can do your arithmetic, lets say `2 + 23`. Presumably, from what you've said, the code currently evaluates this fine and returns `25` - you can get the 16 bit integer you're looking for like so `25 % 16`

Comment: @saad suri I upload it. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Not sure what exactly are you asking, but using `& 0xf` operator on operands and result will ensure 4-bitness

Comment: Alfie Goodacre -- if I have 2 + 23, the result will be (23 - 16 = 7), so 7+2 = 9

Comment: But what happens if i have 4%5 or 4*7 or 5/20

Answer (score 0):

Well an inefficient but easy to implement way would be to repeatedly add or subtract. i.e (2*5) = (2+2+2+2+2).

Integer division would just be the number of times you can subtract before reaching zero (overflow might be an issue).

If you want more efficient or thorough answers, trying looking up binary multiplication/division.